# How do I convert a screen position into an array index?

Tags: java

Suppose i have the following variables:

1. `int width;`: 1 - Integer.MAX_VALUE
2. `int size;`: 1 - width
3. `float x;`: 0.1f - width
4. `int[] cells = new int[size];`

Imagine that `width` is divided into equally sized cells of `width / size`.
Now think that every index in `cells` is linked to one cell.
My problem is that i cannot figure out what the index of the cell at `x` is.
An Example:

```
    width = 300
     size =   3
cell-size = 100

indices:
    0:   0 - 100
    1: 100 - 200
    2: 200 - 300

    x = 250
index =   2
```

```
public static final int WIDTH = 900;
public static final int  SIZE =   3;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] cells = new int[SIZE];
    float x = 447.0f;
    int index = getIndexAt(x);
    System.out.println("Index: " + index + "\nValue: " + cells[index]);
}

public static int getIndexAt(float x) {
    return 0; // How do i get the index for x?
}
```

Comment: `(x / (float) width) * size`?

Comment: You have `100` listed twice, once for 0 and once for 1.  Which is it?

Comment: Also note that not all integer values in 0.1 – Integer.MAX_VALUE can be represented as a float.

Comment: Good point, somewhere around 2^24 (16,777,216) the units digit is no longer significant or tracked by a `float`.

Comment: The method you've written is working, BeUndead. Thank you very much.
Oh, I did not think of the range that a float has. Thanks for noting that.
I wrote down 100 twice for simplicity.